# Data modeling in CoreData, (folders and documents with many children, etc)

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have used CoreData a couple of times but data modeling was very simple. This time I am supposed to implement the following:

- User can create documents and folders (they don't have to be real folders/directories).
- Folders can contain documents or other folders
- Documents have:

  - 1 Title,
  - 1 Description and
  - 8 children
- Each child also has a Title and a Description and could have 8 children
  (optionally)
- This could be as many levels (recursive) as the user desires.

I am not sure how to express this in CoreData. Could someone give a hand here?
Right now I think of:

"Child" entity with "Title" "Description" as attributes and "Children" as a relationship (one to many).
"File" entity with "IsFolder" as a boolean attribute and "Documents" as a relationship (one to many, pointing to "Child")

I am not sure if this well implements above structure in CoreData. 
I am in the right path? Re-modeling data structure in CoreData could be painful (I've heard) so i would like to have a good structure from the beginning. I hope I can get some advice from you;)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this (pseudocode):

```
Folder{
    parent<<--(required,nullify)-->Folder.folders
    folders<--(optional,cascade)-->>Folder.parent
    documents<--(optional,cascade)-->>Document.folder
}

Document{
    title:string
    descriptionText:string
    parent<<--(optional,nullify)-->Document.children
    children<--(optional,cascade)-->>Document.parent
    folder<<--(optional,nullify)-->Folder.document
}
```

(Word of warning: Don't ever use "description" as an attribute name. NSObject has a `description` method so every subclass of NSObject responds to the `description` message. It will cause all kinds of ugly problems if you have an attribute accessor of the same name.)

Comment: I'm working on a similar problem at the moment. I was wondering why your Document objects need children and a parent? I thought that the folder would handle those relationships.

Comment: @nevan -- It was in the design requirement of the parent post. Apparently, he is not modeling just a simple file system. For some reason, his documents can have child documents. I just provided a design that met the requirements. Your requirements may differ but the logic will be similar.